# Возникает ошибка при подключении заголовочных файлов с++

Tags: c++

У меня есть 2 класса Desk и ChessFigure, ошибка возникает, при подключении их заголовочных файлов друг к другу
------1 заголовочный файл -------

```
#pragma once
#include "ChessFigure.h"
class Desk{
    ChessFigure* desk[8][8];
public:
    void AddFig(int x, int y, ChessFigure *fig); 
    void RemoveFig(int x, int y); 
    ChessFigure* GetFigure(int x, int y); 
    Desk();
};
```

----- второй заголовочный файл-----

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "Desk.h"
class ChessFigure{
protected:
    std::string name; 
    bool color; 
    bool life; 
    int weight; 
    struct Coordinates {
        int x; 
        int y; 
    };
    virtual bool CheckMove(int x, int y);
    void Kill(ChessFigure* figure);
    virtual bool IsOnAWay(int x, int y)=0;
    Coordinates* coord = new Coordinates;
    ChessFigure* figure; 
public:
    void SetXY(int x, int y);  
    int GetX(); 
    int GetY(); 
    int GetWeight(); 
    bool GetColor();
    bool GetLife();
    void SetColor(bool color);   
    virtual void Move(int x, int y) = 0;   
    ChessFigure();
    ChessFigure* GetFigure(int x, int y);
};
```

если я в одном из файлов убираю подключение другого программа компилируется
[image: Список ошибок]

Comment: Ну так вы включаете их друг в друга. Зачем вам в `ChessFigure.h` нужен `Desk.h`?

Comment: А зачем вам `#include "Desk.h"` в `ChessFigure.h`?

Comment: чтобы можно было внутри класса пользоваться методами Desk

Comment: Вы же пользуетесь ими при *реализации* методов, а не при их объявлении!..

Comment: Спасибо, я поняла что действительно не нужно повторное подключение

Answer (score 0):

Уберите из `ChessFigure.h` `#include "Desk.h"`, потому что в заголовочном файле `ChessFigure.h` он не нужен. Иначе они друг друга включают и поэтому происходит ошибка.

Comment: @ヒミコ в чём разница между возникает и происходит? :)

Comment: https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: @ヒミコ *появляться; становиться видимым, ощущаемым* - вполне подходит

Comment: @ヒミコ и почему тогда заголовок вопроса не правили? Я из него слова заимствовал :)

Comment: Если вам не нравится исправленная версия, вы можете сделать откат

Comment: @ヒミコ да пусть будет, смысл ответа не поменялся. Просто подумал, что есть какая-то аргументация для правки

Comment: Мне "возникает" нравится больше. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯